# addtionalProperties is not getting validated (flasgger==0.9.2)

Tags: flask, swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi, flasgger

```
 schema:
   type: object
     additionalProperties:
        type: string
```

but even {"key1":12,"asd":2121} is giving 200 response..its getting accepted...but this should not get accepted according to the schema

Comment: `additionalProperties` must be on the same level as `type: object`.

Comment: @Helen- Sorry I had a typing mistake here....its in the same level